# What is the best way to enter data obtained from a database in PHP into seperate html <div>'s?

Tags: javascript, php, html, chat

I'm currently working on a Facebook like chat, with 3 different chat boxes that should work simultaneously. I can send and read messages from my database, but I'm having difficulty displaying this information in the right place. In `chat.php` I have this snippet of code:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "fetch_user_chat_history.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: jQuery.param({receiver_id:receiver_id, num:num}),
            success: function(data) {
                $('$chat_history_'+receiver_id).html(data);
            }
        });
```

Now I am able to read the data from my database correctly in `fetch_user_chat_history.php`, but when I iterate over my messages I'm unable to output them correctly back to chat.php. Here is my `fetch_user_chat_history.php`:

```
<?php
    include "opendb.php";
    session_start();
    $output1 = '';
    $output2 = '';
    $increment = 0;
    $sender = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $receiver_id = $_POST['receiver_id'];
    $chatboxnum = $_POST['num'];
    $query = 'SELECT content, timestamp_chat, sender_id FROM messages WHERE (sender_id = '.$sender.' AND receiver_id = '.$receiver_id.' OR (sender_id = '.$receiver_id.' AND receiver_id = '.$sender.'))';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    switch ($chatboxnum) {
        case 1:
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                if ($row['sender_id']==$sender) {
                    echo '<script>var para = document.createElement("div");';
                    echo 'para.innerHTML = '.$row["content"].';';
                    echo 'var att = document.createAttribute("class");';
                    echo 'att.value = "msg-send";';
                    echo 'para.setAttributeNode(att);';
                    echo 'document.getElementById("sendbox-1").appendChild(para);';
                    echo 'document.body.appendChild(para); </script>';
                }
                else {
                    echo "var element = document.getElementById('receivebox-1'); element.classList.add('msg-receive');";
                }
                $increment += 1;
            }
        break;
    }

?>
```

None of my `echo` statements add anything to `chat.php`. I'm sure there's a very easy fix as I have done this before but I can't seem to get it working. I apologise for the long post.

Comment: Does the PHP code work? Have you tried calling it directly using Postman or similar?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You are not using prepared statements correctly. You need to bind your values.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: _Side note:_ Instead of: `data: jQuery.param({receiver_id:receiver_id, num:num}),`, you can just do: `data: {receiver_id:receiver_id, num:num},`. No need for `jQuery.param()`

Comment: There is NO Benefit (or point) in preparing a query that you have already baked an SQLInjection into :)

Comment: Thank you all for your quick responses. I'm currently just trying to get the chat working, and will look into avoiding SQL injections when it's functional. As for the PHP code, I know it works because when I load fetch_user_chat_history.php in my browser, it shows var element = document.getElementById('receivebox-1'); element.classList.add('msg-receive');.

Comment: would make more sense to put the js code in the `success` function and then get it to process a JSON response of the `$result` array. Then you have flexibility and extensibility

Comment: I thought of trying to process the response in the success function, but I need to maintain the chatboxnum variable to know in which chatbox (1,2 or 3) I should display the messages. But if you think it is a better approach I will look into it. I do wonder however why my code above doesn't work the way it is...